# Where to store Windows Service configuration file

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, visual-c++, windows-services

I'm creating a Windows Service in `C++` that acts as a server. I need to store some configuration values (listening interface, ports) in a text file and other settings and users in a SQLite-Database file. Should I use the `AppData` folder or `System32`, because that's the default Windows Service working directory. Can I use the folder where the `.exe` is located? The Service runs as `LocalSystem`, so I shouldn't have any problem with permissions.

Comment: I think the best place to save config for a windows service is the windows registry.

Comment: you can use and `APPDATA` folder. usually for services it located point to `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming`. some services store own data here

Comment: _"Can I use the folder where the .exe is located?"_ - For services I personally prefer that location because I don't have to search long to find the config files. If you require Windows logo certification, you will propably fail the test as MSFT doesn't like applications writing into the program directory. IMO this makes sense mostly for regular, unprivileged applications but I believe they don't make exceptions for services.

Comment: @zett42 I agree. We do a lot of custom C# services and I always find it easier to stick the config files (never used SqlLite...always a dedicated SQL Server) in the same folder as the executable. It also makes for easy migration. Simply copy the entire folder to a new server, create the service, and go. No other install or configuration to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `C:\ProgramData\MyApp` for data and configuration files, because I need no special permissions to write to this folder and it is very easy to reach.

Even Microsoft's SQL Server writes to the program directory by default, but I think it's not a good place to store data for an application.

Comment: This is supported by the notes from Microsoft: "CommonApplicationData  35  

The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2